# What to call the lump of chewed (chewing) gum?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I sat on a park bench comfortably,  I felt something sticky on my elbow. It is nothing but **a lump of chewed (chewing) gum**. Somebody has stuck it to the back of the bench.

Is there any single word for **a lump of chewed gum** ?

Comment: Sure there is: ***gum***. Consider: *There is some gum on the back of the bench*. Is there any need to further clarify that the gum is no longer in its original wrapper? Seems simple as [ABC](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abc-gum) to me.

Comment: @J.R. To which I would respond "Like, a wad of gum, or a package of gum?" The 'wad' being the chewed version. I would of course expect you to reply 'wad', as a package of gum sitting on the back of a bench is a bit odd.

Comment: @DCS - I _might_ respond with 'wad.' I might also respond with _clump, lump, stale hunk, gooey dollop,_ or _big ol' mass o' gum._ Or perhaps I'd reply, "[It was ABC gum](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abc-gum)."

Comment: It's a package only while it’s wrapped… which here, by definition, it isn't. Single words for chewed gum include "lump" and "piece” and “wad” but any search engine would have told you that so please, what are really asking?

Answer (score 21):

It's called a *wad*.

> **wad** *n*
>   2. A compressed ball, roll, or lump, as of tobacco or chewing gum.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wad).

Comment: Based on the request for a *single* word to describe chewed gum, I dont think "wad" cuts it.  A wad does not implicitly imply it has been chewed.  For example, "I took a wad of 'Big League Chew' gum from the bag".  That implies the wad of gum is unchewed.

Comment: There's no reason *wad* can't describe both things. But the fact is, it perfectly describes chewed gum, and less so your clump of gum shreds.

Comment: Wad does not imply chewed, nor does it imply gum. It is a perfect substitute for "lump" and an excellent substitute for "lump of chewed" but it is not in any way a single-word replacement for "lump of chewed gum." It describes the shape of the object (in this case, gum), not the substance. No one would ever say "My elbow stuck to a wad on the park bench"  unless there was a previous sentence specifying that the speaker was complaining about gum being left around. If someone said "I found a wad on the ground", I'd be more inclined to assume it referred to money.

Comment: It doesn't have to imply those things to be used to describe them. But chewed gum is not important enough to have a word solely used to describe it. You're barking up the wrong tree if  you think that's what this is about.

Comment: The OP is asking for a single word that means "a lump of chewed gum". Your answer states that it's called a "wad", as if that were an answer to the question. So it's absolutely valid for Keltari and NadjaCS to point out that "wad" does not, in fact, mean "a lump of chewed gum". If you want to make the case that there's *no* single word meaning "a lump of chewed gum", that's fine, but you should do it inside the answer. Your answer, as currently worded, is wrong.

Comment: @ruakh Generally gum does not form into a "compressed ball, roll, or lump" until after it's chewed.

Comment: @DCShannon: Hmm. I hope you're wrong, because I've read plenty of old books where kids take a wad of chewing gum out of their pocket and put it in their mouth, and I always assumed that this meant that chewing gum used to come in wad form and not stick form, rather than that they used to reuse [ABC gum](https://www.google.com/search?q=abc+gum) . . . but you could be right. Regardless, I was trusting in Robusto's comments where he claimed that *wad* does not specifically mean what his answer claimed. Either his answer or his comments are wrong (and his comments are wrongheaded either way).

Comment: @ruakh It's certainly possible I'm wrong, but I've always interpreted such a sentence as implying that they're putting previously chewed gum back in their mouth. I don't think a 'wad' *has* to have been chewed. If you had some gum that did not come in a stick, like maybe Bazooka, then you could perhaps call that a wad, but I think wad strongly *implies* that it has been chewed, especially given that most gum comes in a stick, which is definitely *not* a wad.